# JavaScript new Date(string) returns different results on exactly identical date strings

Tags: javascript, string, date

I would like to share something I found with JavaScript today.

[Simple example here](http://jsfiddle.net/5tjNa/1/)

```
d1 = "￼￼￼￼￼￼￼2014-07-15T14:00:00.000Z"
d2 = "2014-07-15T14:00:00.000Z"
```

The input strings are ISO formatted using `new Date().toISOString();`.
I received the first date from a server where it was stored in mongoDB as ISOString, and the second one was created manually.

If I do `new Date(d1);`, it returns 'Invalid Date' but if I do the same for `d2` it returns the correct date.

Comment: `console.log(d1.length); console.log(d2.length);`

Comment: `console.log(d1===d2);
console.log(escape(d1));
console.log(escape(d2));`

Comment: Thanks guys found the invisible character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one contains non printable

```
0x20 0x3D 0x20 0x22
```

characters

Comment: oh my god?? so there's invisible characters hiding in front of the first date string?

Comment: oh I see.. Tried deleting the first character of the first date then manually put 2 and it produced Date.. I have no idea where that characters came from. but Thanks for the answer!